# Linq SelectMany project to index

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 different collections.

pseudo code:

```
// index string by int : Dictionary<int, string>
index = { 0, "a" }, { 1, "b" }, { 2, "c" }

// data : Dictionary<string, List<Data>>
data = {"a", { "data00", "data01"..}}, 
       {"b", {"data20", "data21", "data22"...}}, 
       {"c", {"data4",...}}...
```

I want project int index to data string value and

```
var result = data.SelectMany ... new { IntIndex, DataValue }
```

I need to flatten lists into one sequence and pair the `Data` values with `int` index using `string` index.

Comment: Could you show us some example output?

Comment: _int index to data string value_ - that would have to be _values_.

Comment: Your `data` contains the key `"a"` twice, that's not possible in a `Dictionary<,>`. Is your data structure really something else, or did you copy the data incorrectly?

Comment: It's like your `index` dictionary is the "wrong direction", it's a dictionary from `int` to `string`, but you want to go the other way. Do you know that no string is a value of many int keys inside `index`?

Comment: I edited the question. obviously there cant be duplicates.... sooo.. now we are downvoting for everything including typos... cool.

Comment: I think you getting dv's for too much pseudo in your pseudo code. You have accpeted an answer but the question remains unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have slightly update types and values (your Dictionary contains duplicated keys and index wasn't specified) but it shouldn't be a problem. You may modify function easily for your data types.

```
var index = new List<Tuple<int, string>> {Tuple.Create(0, "a"), Tuple.Create(1, "b")};

var data = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>()
    {
        {"a", new[] {"data00", "data01"}},
        {"b", new[] {"data20", "data21", "data22"}},
        {"c", new[] {"data4"}}
    };

var result = index
    .Join(data, x => x.Item2, y => y.Key, (x,y) => new KeyValuePair<int, IEnumerable<string>>(x.Item1, y.Value))
    .SelectMany(x => x.Value, (x, y) => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(x.Key, y));
```

Comment: The `Tuple.Create` method is shorter that `new Tuple<...,...>`.  Also, if you can avoid tuples and use anonymous types your code will generally be more readable - which is possible here since there's no public API.

Comment: @EamonNerbonne thank you for constructive criticism. Have changed code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your duplication of `keys` was accidental, you could try this

```
Dictionary<int, List<Data>> intData = new Dictionary<int, List<Data>>();

foreach (var iVal in index)
{
     List<Data> tmpList = new List<Data>();

     if (data.TryGetValue(iVal.Value, out tmpList))
     {
         intData.Add(iVal.Key, tmpList);
     }
}
```

If you can have duplicate keys then a dictionary is not the right structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
var index = new List<Tuple<int, string>> {Tuple.Create(0, "a"), Tuple.Create(1, "b")};

var data = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>()
{
    {"a", new[] {"data00", "data01"}},
    {"b", new[] {"data20", "data21", "data22"}},
    {"c", new[] {"data4"}}
};

var res = 
(from i in index
join d in data on i.Item2 equals d.Key
select new {Key = i.Item1, Value = d.Value})
.SelectMany(x => x.Value, (x, v) => new {x.Key, Value = v});
```